# Insert seq.nextval and seq.currval

Tags: oracle

Is this the best way to handle this insert, such that columns test1 and test2 are always equal?

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_temp
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 50
  NOCYCLE;


CREATE TABLE test_tbl (
  test1 NUMBER,
  test2 NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO test_tbl
  SELECT
    seq_temp.nextval,
    seq_temp.currval
  FROM dual;
```

Comment: If you always want to have the same values, then why have two columns at all? If you only want to make them the same during an insert a trigger is more reliable.

Comment: test1 is the key to the row.  In this case, we want test2 to refer to test1, but that is not always the case.  Test1 could also refer to another value.  It is similar to a linked list.  Not my design, BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no difference - you must use nextval for at least one column, but for the other column nextval and currval will be the same value.

In other words, all the following statements will have the same effect:

```
SELECT seq_temp.nextval, seq_temp.currval FROM dual;

SELECT seq_temp.nextval, seq_temp.nextval FROM dual;

SELECT seq_temp.currval, seq_temp.nextval FROM dual;
```